# Bitbucket pipelines slow on build setup

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using bitbucket pipelines to admin deploys to master. Normally, it spend from 10 to 15 seconds to make deploy, but today, im having problems with it.

Pipeline have been deployed on 4 minutes, all of it time ocurr on build setup section.

I dont change anything on bitbucket-pipelines.yml so... I dont know why it is happened?

[image]

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That may happen due to outages in Bitbucket's infrastructure.

Sadly, they are usually not acknowledged by https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/ unless they are persistent on long periods. But now that you realized this degraded performance you could claim not to be charged those CI minutes if it was truly Bitbucket's fault.

---

If you were using your private CI executors, monitor your infrastructure as it might be the root cause for this issues.

---

Also, presence of unusually bloated caches or artifacts could slow down build setups, so make sure you tuned those right.